# Relationships in Laravel

Tags: php, orm, relationship, laravel, eloquent

I have two tables, `Galleries` and `Gallery_items`.
In `Galleries` I save information like who the author is. In `Gallery_items` I save each picture that the gallery contains.

Now I want to **get the first picture in *each* gallery *where* the title is mona lisa *and where* the author is Leonardo da Vinci**.

I tested:

```
Gallery_items::group_by('gallery_id')->where('title', '=', 'mona lisa')->gallery()->where('author', '=', 'Leonardo da Vinci');
```

But it doesn't work. I get an error `Method [gallery] is not defined on the Query class.`.

But I have added gallery() to the model.

```
class Gallery_items extends Eloquent
{
    public function gallery()
    {
        return $this->belongs_to('gallery');
    }
}
```

Any idea how I should do?
Is this even possible with one query?
Is "[Constraining Eager Loading](http://laravel.com/docs/database/eloquent#constraining-eager-loads)" maybe the answer (I don't get what that is)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to @AndHeiberg i started to see the problem from other perspectives and I have now solved the problem using a `JOIN` statement.

```
Gallery_items::join('gallery', 'Gallery_items.gallery_id', '=', 'gallery.id'))->group_by('gallery_id')->where_title_and_author('Mona Lisa', 'Leonardo da Vinci');
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
Gallery_items->group_by('gallery_id')->where_title_and_author('Mona Lisa', 'Leonardo da Vinci');
```

Comment: No because `Gallery_items` doesn't have a column called `author`. It is the `Gallery` that has that column.